# Firebase - Relacionamento entre documentos

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebase, nosql

Eu sei que o firebase é NoSQL/NoREL, mas tenho essa dúvida e que é bem relevante dado ao projeto que estou desenvolvendo.

No modelo tradicional do MySQL, quando temos uma tabela de `categorias`, por exemplo e uma tabela `posts` e existe uma relação entre elas, uma categoria que tem posts atrelados a ela, geralmente não pode ser deletada.

Como isso é feito no Firebase, já que qualquer documento pode ser deletado. E no caso da categoria ser deletada, como fica o post "orfão"?

Gostaria de entender melhor como isso funciona, pois estou acostumado com o modelo relacional e estou tendo dificuldades nesse ponto com bancos NoSQL.

OBS: Estou usando o Firestore, que é atualmente uma versão BETA.

Comment: Realtime database ou cloud firestore?

Comment: Estou usando o Firestore!

Comment: Cada caso é um caso, depende muito do que quer fazer com o banco, dê uma olhada na [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data?authuser=0&hl=pt-br) para ter uma ideia

Comment: Desculpa @GuilhermeCostamilam,  achei seu comentário um pouco genérico, mas tudo bem. Estou vendo aqui mais detalhes sobre isso, apesar da falta de tempo, vou ter que mergulhar mais fundo na documentação.

Comment: No Firestore, você pode fazer isso através de [regras de segurança](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started?hl=pt-br). Se você postar a sua coleção "posts" e "categorias", posso lhe ajudar a escrever as regras.

Comment: De fato essa é uma boa discussão. Acredito que por desempenho, relacionar os documentos e separar por assuntos seria a melhor pedida. Tenho estudado o assunto agora e tenho relacionado os documentos pela ID do doc (vicio do relacional rs). Agora garantir a integridade que ainda não esta claro pra mim.